# jQuery: Unsupported Media Type with Form Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am uploading Form Data by REST API and I have the following code what I am using. It is giving me Error Code 415 with Unsupported Media Type.

Please correct me where I am wrong.

```
var device = new FormData();
device.append("device_id", "2");
device.append("Img","D:\\Main\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\img\\default.png");

$.ajax(
        { 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: getApiURL(25),
            data: device,
            processData: false,
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
            headers: { 
                "Authorization": "Basic " + base_64_firebase_token,
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            success : function(data){
                callback(data);
            }, 
            error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(ajaxOptions);
                console.log("Error!!!"+throwError);
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only static image then do it on your server side if still want or user added image you have to send then do following:

For correct form data usage you need to do 2 steps.

**Preparations**

You can give your whole form to FormData() for processing

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

or specify exact data for FormData()

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('section', 'general');
formData.append('action', 'previewImg');
// Attach file
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

**Sending form**

Ajax request with jquery will looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    // ... Other options like success and etc
});
```

After this it will send ajax request like you submit regular form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Update: This request cannot work without `type:"POST"` in options since all files must be sent via POST request.

**Note:**  `contentType: false` only available [from jQuery 1.6 onwards](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank @Nikhil. I tried what you suggest, it removed the error Error Code of 415 but file is not being sent to the server. I used reader blob to send the file data, that is also not working

Comment: if you are using php on server side please do `print_r($_FILES)`. if it contains data then you will know that your file came to server. because initially uploaded files gets into `tmp` folder and then we move that file from that location to destination.

Comment: I am only using jQuery no PHP

Comment: Hi, I've post my answer. Please visit once.

Comment: "contentType: false only available from jQuery 1.6 onwards" — Note that jQuery 1.x and 2.x are beyond end of life and don't get security updates, so nobody should be using a version of jQuery that old anyway.

Comment: can i get to know, what type of security updates needed on front end side.

Comment: I tried this method (with a csv file) but I have problems receiving the file in chrome mobile browser (in the standard desktop browser it works great). Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

In your AJAX call you need to set your content type:

```
headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
```

Comment: A FormData object does not get converted to JSON (and XHR will generate a suitable content type for it if not overridden)